# The mean of a data frame is not ouputting the right value in R

Tags: r, dataframe, mean

I have a situation. The mean I am getting is not right for multiple id's and have figured something out as well, the problem but looking for guidance on a possible solution.

My data is in a data frame.

1. I have created a data frame "b" before the for loop. A for loop to read the files.
2. Within the for loop I am assigning all the files to "b" by b<-c(b,data[pollutent])
3. The class of b is a data.frame
4. The names function on "b" shows one column which is the argument provided for pollutent in the function call
5. When i return b, it shows me the right results but for multiple id's, they come in different sections. for example, for 70:72 it shows

   ```
   1st
   $nitrate...underneath the values
   2nd
   $nitrate...underneath values
   3rd
   $nitrate...and values
   ```

Problem: when I go on to calculate the mean for multiple id's, it is only considering the first set of data which is from the first file.

The function call is `A1p1("specdata","nitrate",70:72)`.

I am also pasting a sample output below from the function

```
$nitrate
   [1]      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA
  [11]      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA
  [21]      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA
.............
$nitrate
   [1]      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA
  [11]      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA
  [21]      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA
............
$nitrate
   [1]      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA
  [11]      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA
  [21]      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA
```

Is there a remedy anyone can suggest?

The full code I am using is  below:

**

```
A1p1 <- function(directory,pol,id)
{

  filename <- list.files(pattern=".csv")
  a <- data.frame()

  for( i in 1:length(id))
  {

    data <- read.csv(paste(directory,"/",sprintf('%03d',id[i]),".csv",sep=""),header=T)
    a <- c(a,data[pol])

  }


if(pollutent=="aa")
  {
    me <- mean(a$aa,na.rm=T)
  }
  else
  {
    me <- mean(a$bb,na.rm=T)
  }

  return(round(me,digits=3)) 
}
```

Comment: Welcome, but I've downvoted your question. It is difficult to see what is being asked here. I had a go, and could probably decipher after another few reads, but it'd be better if you clarified your question substantially.

Answer (score 0):

`c()` it not the right way to combine data.frames. Do you want to stack rows on top of each other? Then `rbind()` is the right function. Do you want to add columns to an existing data.frame? Then `cbind` is the right choice. Do you want to merge data.frames by a common value? Then `merge` would be the correct function. It's not clear at all what you are trying to do with this data.

A for look probably isn't needed here. You could do

```
mylist<-lapply(paste(directory,"/",sprintf('%03d',id[i]),".csv",sep=""), read.csv,header=T)
```

to get a list containing all of your data.frames, and then stack them on top of each other with

```
do.call(rbind, mylist)
```

assuming they all have the same column names and that's the result you want.